# When to use views_get_view_result

Tags: 7, views

I have a View of nested taxonomy terms. As I filter using a somehow convolute logic (GET parameters, URL-frienly parameters and user permissions), I use

```
 $list = views_get_view_result("NAME_OF_MY_VIEW");

 foreach($list as $item){
     ... -> handle the fields.
```

And in my custom module I use `MYMODULE_views_pre_view` to set the different filters:

```
$filters = $view->display_handler->get_option('filters');
$handler_name = 'field_rf_product_value_1'; 
$terms = mega_convolute_function( $handler_name ); // extract data from several sources.
$handler = $view->display_handler->get_handler('filter', $handler_name);
$handler->value = $terms;
```

Is that a correct procedure? Using only the `views` function I start to see problems to appear, for example I can only get access to0 the raw image field path, *"[uri] => public://category/cables.png"* (for example), so if I want to show the thumbnail I would need to use the Drupal function `image_style_url`, i.e., I get some freedom to feed the filter data but I start to loose the properties set in the Views UI. What would be the spirit of the `views_get_view_result` function ?

Comment: Hello there. Could you re-phrase the question a bit? I don't get the part with the Raw Image Field Path and how it connects to setting filters in Views. Cheers!

Comment: Hi. I have re-phrased the question. I hope it is better understood. I would need to know the best approach to the problem of getting many complex data retrieval logic and the easyness of using views_get_view_result, and the difficulties that could arise from that approach.